# why I cant use getCollection() or getData() after using join?

Tags: php, magento

```
$datas = $collection->getSelect()->join(array('B' => $table), 'main_table.entity_id = B.parent_id', array());
```

when I try to use:

```
$datas->getCollection();
```

or:

```
$datas->getData();
```

I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Select_Exception' with message 'Unrecognized method 'getData()'' in
```

and how can I use addFieldToFilter() after using a "join"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're assigning the result of a Zend DB statement to your `$datas` variable, which would make it an instance of `Zend_Db_Select` rather than a collection.

You should just make changes by reference rather than assigning it to your variable.

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(...
```

Then continue to use `$collection`:

```
foreach ($collection as $entity) {
    print_r($entity->getData());
}
```